# grails initializing bean load order

Tags: json, spring, grails, grails3

Using grails: 3.1.12

**[The problem]**

I have created a plugin which creates a JSON named configuration on initialization so it can be used afterwards.

The bean:

```
    MyBean implements InitializingBean{
        void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
            JSON.createNamedConfig('mycfg',{
               it.registerObjectMarshaller(new MyObjectMarshaller())
            })
        }
    }
```

Plugin:

```
    Closure doWithSpring() { {->
       "myBean"(MyBean){}
    }}
```

But when I want to use the configuration and convert a simple HashMap, it will complaint that there is no Marshaller found.

```
   JSON.use 'mycfg',{([a:'3'] as JSON).toString()}
```

Exception

```
  Caused by: org.grails.web.converters.exceptions.ConverterException: Unconvertable Object of class: java.util.LinkedHashMap
at grails.converters.JSON.value(JSON.java:182)
at grails.converters.JSON.render(JSON.java:119)
```

**[Investigation]**

JSON creates a delegating defaultconfiguration when createNamedConfig is called and use it as an argument for the createNamedConfig closure. I discovered the argument configuration does not equal the one when grails is loaded (this is a Chainedconfiguration). The chainedconfiguration is setup by grails in ConvertersConfigurationInitializer and this is loaded after the initialization of the InitializingBean of my plugin. So JSON does not know of the default grails configuration when my plugin bean initializes.

**[Question]**

Is it possible to ensure that the MyBean afterPropertiesSet is loaded after the ConvertersConfigurationInitializer afterPropertiesSet? (without referencing ConvertersConfigurationInitializer directly in MyBean)

Answer (score 0):

You can control the load order by using `loadAfter` property. Please check this out - [plugin docs - understanding load order](http://docs.grails.org/latest/guide/plugins.html#understandingPluginLoadOrder)

Please see `Controlling Load Order` part of this section.